How do I run DOS 2.0 .exe and .com programs from my .exe program?
I'm writing a very small .exe program in assembly, targeting DOS 2.0 (or, if it doesn't work, DOS 3.00 is also fine). It has to be able to run other DOS .com and .exe programs, wait for them to finish, get their resources (e.g. filehandles and memory) freed, and get the exit code. It has to pass arguments to these other programs. The environment variables don't matter, it can propagate its own environment, or construct a new, empty one. The other programs are quite simple (they read some files, and then they write some files), they are not command.com, and they don't run other programs, they are not TSRs, they are not .bat files.
How do I run other .exe and .com programs on DOS, from my very small .exe program? I need code in assembly language, or a tutorial.

This is int 21h / ah=4bh.  http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2939.htm

@NateEldredge: Thanks, I'll give it a try based on those docs. It doesn't explain though how I get the exit code of the other program.

A simple program just runs service 4B00h and, if it succeeds, gets the exit code using service 4Dh. The callver program actually uses COMSPEC to allow running other sorts of scripts and programs, but it is easy to pass an executable pathname to service 4B00h instead. Of course the 4B00h call requires to have enough free DOS memory, so you may want to shrink your allocation before running exec.

Are these sub-programs made by you, or do you even know if they return an exit code - DOS 2.X was first DOS to even allow that, so many programs continued to exit the old way without specifying a return code.

@Justme Programs returning using int 20h, interrupt 21h service 00h, or a retn instruction will all pass a return code of 0 to the calling process.

@ecm I know. That's why I asked OP how the subprograms return, if they even return in a way that the return code can be specified.

@Justme: These programs exit with the service 4Ch, specifying an exit code. For programs exiting any of the old ways, it's fine that I receive a 0 as an implicit exit code.

+1 for having the courage to write this post in 2024

To run a separate program, the appropriate service is interrupt 0x21 service 0x4B, variant 0 in your case; so
    mov ax, 4b00h
    int 21h

Additional arguments need to be provided before this:

DS:DX points to the program name (including extension), zero-terminated;
ES:BX points to the parameter block, which points to the environment, command-line arguments and FCBs to provide to the called program.

You also need to ensure there’s enough available memory. In most cases, you’ll have to reduce your memory allocation.
The service returns when the program exits, or if it fails to start the program — carry will be set in the latter case. If the program ran, you can retrieve its exit code by calling service 0x4D; you’ll get the return code in AL and the exit type in AH (0 for a normal exit).
See article 10, “The MS-DOS EXEC Function”, in section 2 of the MS-DOS Encyclopedia for details.

Missing two parts: 21.4B can fail to execute your application and will return CY then, NC if it successfully ran the application. And you got the flat (.COM) format vs MZ format the wrong way around: For a flat format program you always want to shrink the allocation; for MZ format programs this may or may not be needed. That is, depending on whether the "max allocation" MZ header field is set to a low value or a high value. Flat format files always run as if given a max allocation value of 0FFFFh, so the loader allocates to you the largest memory block in full.

My almost complete example here: https://github.com/joshudson/dossuperfloppy/blob/10110d40cc7de0a4b81b60df401706ab860af42b/formathd.asm#L622 (doesn't pass FCBs beause FORMAT.COM (and most other programs for that matter) doesn't care). Self memory shrinking is at the top of the file.

It's great to have all these details and example source code pieced together, thanks for the answer and the comments!
